# LaTeX: Strange "La, Lb" showing in nested enumerate

Tags: latex

I'm writing a big LaTeX document. In it I have a nested enumerate environment:

```
\begin{enumerate}
     \item Bla bla
     \item More Bla Bla
     \item Now we nest:
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item Nested Bla Bla
        \item ...And more
        \end{enumerate}
     \item Back from enumeration
\end{enumerate}
```

The problem: In the output the enumeration of the nested part is with "La", "Lb" etc.

As I said, it's a complex document and I'm sure the error is somewhere in the definitions/document class. So I don't expect a solution; rather, I hope that someone can pinpoint me as where to search, and what exactly to search (for example, what commands modify the numbering in enumerate environment in the first place?)

Comment: Please use binary search to generate a minimal working example. (Throw out half the code to see if the problem is still there. If so, repeat, else put it back and try throwing away the other half. Etc.) Then when you have a small document in which the error is still present, and in which no line can be omitted without making the error go away (or the document stop compiling), post the document if you still haven't figured out the error, and others can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example above reproduces fine on my machine. Here's the output (as expected)

[image]

Now if you *wanted* to change the list numbering to look like `(La)`, `(Lb)` etc, you'd add something like this to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{(L\alph{enumii})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
```

which will produce and output like

[image]

So you should look in your preamble/definitions to see if you've made any modifications like this.

Comment: No, it seems I don't have something like that.

Comment: @Gadi: Is what I've shown a correct representation of your output?

Comment: Indeed, but I don't think it's caused by the same reason. I have no idea how that "L" slipped in...

Comment: @Gadi: Since you say it's a complicated, long document, such errors could have slipped in due to a typo. I can't think of any other reason why you would get an "L" in there. Perhaps some poorly written macros that you didn't know about (co-authors or copied code...)?

Comment: That's exactly my line of thought. Problem is I don't know what to look for. Of course, the only solution right now is to start removing things until I end up with a "sterilized" version still containing the error; but I hoped before I start with that I'll be able to pinpoint the problem with a simple grep.

Comment: It might be easier if you posted your preamble as an edit to the question. If I can reproduce the error with that preamble, then we know that that's where the problem is. If not, it's somewhere in the body.

Comment: Oh, and also you can enter an enumeration number manually like `\item[La] blah blah` instead of modifying in the preamble. Can you check if there's something like that in your tex file?

Comment: I finally found the problematic definition:
"\def\L{{\cal L}}"